# Can't break a line with string in optparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, optparse

I am trying to break a line with \n with optparse. Example: line1 \n line2
But when I type \n it doesn't break it just prints it as line1 \n line2, instead of  doing a break. Here is my code:

```
import optparse
import sys

def main():
    progparse = optparse.OptionParser("usage " + "--message <text here>")
    progparse.add_option("--message", dest="msg_txt", type="string", help="Type the message you want to send")

    msg_txt = ""

    if (options.msg_txt == None):
        print(progparse.usage)
        sys.exit()

    print(options.msg_txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I just do a simple print statment with \n then it will break the line, why doesn't it do it when using optparse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

option1, use *real* new line in your input:

```
$ python3 test.py --message "line1
> line2
> line3"
line1
line2
line3
```

option2, eval `\n` as real new line with [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
print(ast.literal_eval('"' + options.msg_txt + '"'))
```

note this may raise an exception for ill-formed input.